# Jetpack compose - On Android versions less than 10 the shadow will not be drawn for the concave paths

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable

I created a custom shape through Shape interface and added it to the Card composable through **shape** parameter. Unfortunately, elevation/shadow cannot be applied on the Android versions below 10. Above 10, it works fine.

Is there any other elegant solution to apply elevation to the Card/Surface?
Example of custom shape: https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42

**TicketShape**

```
class TicketShape(private val cornerRadius: Float) : Shape {

override fun createOutline(
    size: Size,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    density: Density
): Outline {
    return Outline.Generic(
        // Draw your custom path here
        path = drawTicketPath(size = size, cornerRadius = cornerRadius)
    )
  }
}
```

Drawing TicketShape

```
fun drawTicketPath(size: Size, cornerRadius: Float): Path {
return Path().apply {
    reset()
    // Top left arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = -cornerRadius,
            top = -cornerRadius,
            right = cornerRadius,
            bottom = cornerRadius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 90.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    lineTo(x = size.width - cornerRadius, y = 0f)
    // Top right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - cornerRadius,
            top = -cornerRadius,
            right = size.width + cornerRadius,
            bottom = cornerRadius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 180.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height - cornerRadius)
    // Bottom right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - cornerRadius,
            top = size.height - cornerRadius,
            right = size.width + cornerRadius,
            bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 270.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    lineTo(x = cornerRadius, y = size.height)
    // Bottom left arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = -cornerRadius,
            top = size.height - cornerRadius,
            right = cornerRadius,
            bottom = size.height + cornerRadius
        ),
        startAngleDegrees = 0.0f,
        sweepAngleDegrees = -90.0f,
        forceMoveTo = false
    )
    lineTo(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius)
    close()
  }
}
```

**Ticket card**

```
@Composable
fun TicketCard(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
Card(
    modifier = modifier
        .width(307.dp)
        .height(171.dp),
    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background,
    shape = TicketShape(LocalDensity.current.run { 14.dp.toPx() }),
    elevation = 12.dp
) {
    
  }
}
```

**Result Android >=10**
[Card has elevation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR5d8.png)

**Result Android <10** Card has no elevation
[Proof that card is drawn correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Tea.png)

[Documentation regarding elevation restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgRmM.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of linking to a large article. Also check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you @PhilipDukhov, I made an edit. Is it more clear on what is the problem?

Comment: Oh, so this is intended behaviour because of some Compose limitations, from reading your original question I thought that it's a bug. I don't know how to bypass it. But generally Compose shadow problems are [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122) of the most starred issues. Also you shouldn't use image of documentation on SO, instead you should format it as a quoted text - in this case it'll be much cleaner.